# How configure eclipselink jpa dialect for custom isolation levels

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, transaction-isolation

I am using Spring 3.2.1 and EclipseLink 2.4 and JPA 2.0

I get an error when I use other than the default isolation level.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels - use a special JpaDialect for your JPA implementation
```

Is EclipseLinkJpaDialect need to extend the class?

How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set isolation level in @Transactional "READ\_UNCOMMITTED". I am using EclipseLink 2.5.1-RC1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337106/how-to-set-isolation-level-in-transactional-read-uncommitted-i-am-using-ecli)

Answer (score 0):

What isolation level are you trying to use?  Normally you would set your desired isolation level as your database default (to avoid having to set it on every connection).

You can make EclipseLink set the database transaction isolation level through using a SessionCustomizer and the DatabaseLogin API, setTransactionIsolation().

Comment: Hi. For example serializable. I did some try, but did not work. Do you have an example of follow?