# How to set isolation level in @Transactional "READ_UNCOMMITTED". I am using EclipseLink 2.5.1-RC1

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, transactional, transaction-isolation, read-uncommitted

I have a requirement to start new Transaction within an ongoing Transaction so that an exception in 2nd transaction will rollback only new transaction not the old one.

This I am doing by setting propagation attribute in 2nd transaction like this:

> @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

This created a new Transaction, but the new Transaction needs to read some uncommitted data of the first transaction (dirty read), and also update that data. This I am trying to do by setting isolation attribute as :

> @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)

This throws an Exception - InvalidIsolationLevelException, saying "Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels - use a special JpaDialect for your JPA implementation".

Can any help me to implement JpaDialect? I am using Eclipse Link 2.5.1 .

Or can I some how close the first transaction before starting a new transaction? Since First transaction is closed, the Second will have no problem reading the data committed by First Transaction.

Comment: Is there any way I can explicitly close a transaction started by @Transactional annotation within that method itself??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring managed transactions, EclipseLink JPA, custom isolation level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293945/spring-managed-transactions-eclipselink-jpa-custom-isolation-level)

Answer (score 1):

- In JPA you can try somehting like this, not much certain on how to achieve similar in EclipseLink/Spring.

  But the overall concept might remain same, get the underlying database connection & set appropriate isolation level.

  ```
  java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
  connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED); 
  //-- Or with some other constant something like Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED
  ```

  Afterwards, you might also want to reset the isolation level back to the default.
- If you don't want to make changes, then you might need to implement `JpaDialect` overriding methods to accommodate the change for isolation level in transaction.

  You can refer [here](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-change-transaction-isolation-level-example) which describes implementation for Hibernate, can try similar for EclipseLink.